# Searching for string whilst removing a certain part of the search term string

Tags: jquery, html, regex

Im trying to find a string but remove a certain part of the string from my search through regex. I have a checkbox with a label, and I am trying to search for a link with the same value as the label but without a part of the label's string (a value wrapped in parenthesis). After this the link should be hidden. Here is what I have so far:

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="sector1" />
<label for="sector1">Some kind of string (22)</label>
<a class="select-filter-option">Some kind of string</a>
```

JQuery:

```
if (!$(this).is(':checked')) {

    var searchType = $(this).next().text(/\(.*?\)/g);

    $('.search-filter-wrap a:contains(' + searchType + ')').hide();

};
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used `replace()` to accomplish that by stripping the parenthesis part:

```
var searchType = $("input").next().text().replace(/[^.*]\(.*\)/g, '');
```

Eplaination:
`[^.*]` : means NOT anything
`\(.*\)` : means anything with parenthesis around them

[FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/RA2Qd/)

Room for optimization: Remove the last parenthesis `\)` so that everything after the first gets removed.

```
/[^.*]\(.*/
```

Or make sure that the parenthesis did not belong to the actual text by forcing numbers in between them:

```
/[^.*]\([0-9]+\)/g
```

Note that a second (or multiple) occurrence of parenthesis is not *specifically* handled (i.e. `Some kind of string (112) (22)` will probably give undesired behaviour).

Also note that jQuery's `text()` does not take regular expressions, afaik.

Comment: Brilliant just what I was looking for! Thanks for the concise answer, appreciate the help.